# How to use class inheritance for unittest with Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, inheritance

I need to write a unittest for the following class:

```
 class Calculator:
    def __Puissance(self, a):
        return(a*10)
    def sum(self, a, b):
        return (self.__Puissance(a) + self.__Puissance(b))
```

This is my try (I didn't implement the assert yet):

```
import unittest  

class calculator2(Calculator):
    def __Puissance(self,a):
        return(a*1000)

class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = calculator2()
    def test_sum(self):
        answer = self.calc.sum(2, 4)
        print(answer)
```

My question is the following: I'm trying to mock the function called  `__Puissance` which belonged to `Calculator` class by using the `__Puissance` from `Calculator2` class, but as the first one is private function to `Calculator` class it couldn't be mocked and `sum()` function use it .How can I mock the `__Puissance` function without modifying private declaration of it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show what you've tried and what's got you stuck, we're more than happy to help with questions like that :)

Comment: Why are you trying to mock "private" methods? Also, why are you using a `__double_underscore` name (*especially* if you actually want to be able to override it)?

Comment: In fact the scirpt that I'm working on it  is so complex to discuss about it here. so I've presented this simple example to know how to stub a private function.

Comment: Why is that a class?

Comment: If you have the hand on the class definition, make `__Puissance` an implementation method (using a single leading underscore) instead. Else, the real name of the method (for the outside world) is actually `_Calculator__Puissance` (and is no more "private" than anything in python).

Comment: my goal is to mock the __Puissance private function by using another one which doesn't the same inherited function's process.
I know that the mock is possible if it was a global function or an implementation method.